# Appending string to img src in angular 4

Tags: angular

How can we append string to src content.

```
<img [src] = "data.imagePath"+".jpg">
```

I know its wrong.

But in angular version 1 we could achieve this

```
<img ng-src="{{data.imagePath}}.jpg">
```

My json is providing only the name of picture without extension. So how could I achieve this in angular 4.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this :

```
<img src = "{{data.imagePath}}.jpg">
```

or

```
<img [src] = "data.imagePath+'.jpg'">
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
<img [src]="data.imagePath + '.jpg'" />
```

should work.